# How Can I Create a Distribution Visualization for an Average Day?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-visualization

In R, my dataframe ("sampledata") looks like this:

[image: data in R]

- The timestamp column is POSIXct, format: "2018-10-01 00:03:23"
- The state column is Factor w/ 3 levels "AVAILABLE", "MUST_NOT_RUN", "MUST_RUN"
- There are 6 unique device_id. The timestamps for each device are not the same, meaning data was not always collected at the same minute for each device. In some cases, there are multiple records per minute for the same device.

I want to transform the data into a visualization that shows distribution of "state" across a "typical" day. Ideally, something like this:

[image: Desired Visualization]

I've tried to count each occurrence of "state" grouped by timestamp minutes but failed (Error: can't sum factors). I've been trying to use ggplot and geom_area for the visualization, but believe I need to restructure my data before it will work. Very new to R (obviously). Happy to read any tutorials or links provided as background and appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks!

Other information that may/may not be helpful:

- There are a handful of columns in the dataframe not shown.
- 223,446 entries between 10/2/18 - 11/8/18.

Comment: Please provide a dataset that can be used for reproduction, for instance using ´dput()´.

Comment: What file format is this?

Comment: Straight output from dput()... happy to reoutput if needed?

Comment: @Mr.Zen Its a text file with a R `structure` instruction. I have edited the file with a text editor and included `obj <-` right at the beginning.

Comment: @johnwonderbread When the dataset is too big the output of `dput(head(df, 20))` will do. (`df` is the name of your dataset.) Most often we only need an example, not the full data.

Comment: Please reupload a subset of the data. I cannot even paste the ´structure()´ you uploaded into my console without RStudio crashing, because it's so large.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here you go. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9magnuv3erf2js9/sampledata?dl=0

Comment: Thanks, @RuiBarradas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the hours from the timestamps and then compute proportions of your states by hour:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

#get hours from timestamp
obj$hour <- as.POSIXlt(obj$timestamp)$hour 

#get average state proportions per hour
plot_obj <- ddply(obj,.(hour), #take data.frame "obj" and group by "hour"
      function(x) with(x,                      
                         data.frame(100*table(state)/length(state))))



ggplot(plot_obj, aes(x=hour,y=Freq,fill=state)) +
  geom_area()
```

Comment: I haven't done any formatting yet, but this appears to have done the trick. As I understand it, you're creating a column to represent the hour of the day that the data was recorded. Can you help me understand the creation of plot_obj and the with statement you're using? Assuming you're counting the percent of total records with that response for the hour, but the "Freq" column sometimes adds to just over or just under 100. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, the as.POSIXlt(...)$hour... what other commands work? $minute? $day (just tried this one and it didn't seem to fly).

Comment: Very nice solution. But there is a jagged upper line due to round off errors. Why `round(., 2)`? Without it the graph is even nicer. Try it. Upvote.

Comment: Edited out the rounding, does not make sense here, you're right. Basically, you take the data.frame obj, group it by hour and then create the proportions by applying a function on the grouped data.frame.

Regarding the as.POSIXlt() command, you can find the different date-time classes here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html